# How to actually click a generated right click menu?

Tags: c#, datagridview, menu, click

I've generated a context menu in `dataGridView`'s `RowHeaderMouseClick` event. Here is the code:

```
private void dataGridView_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
            menu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Delete"));
            menu.Show(dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
}
```

There is some this kind of problems asked but I couldn't make it to find the solution. How can I click that "Delete"?

I achieved to delete the row with `RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick`  event before, here it is:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        try {
            Excel.Application xlApplication = (Excel.Application) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook) xlApplication.ActiveWorkbook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            ((Excel.Range) xlWorksheet.Rows[dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 2]).Delete(Type.Missing);
            dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
        } catch {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not update the Excel file. Make sure the file is open.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

So if I find the solution, I can simply copy this to new Click event.

Comment: Make your MenuItem a local variable and add a click event to it using +=.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
      MenuItem deleteMenu = new MenuItem( "Delete" );
      deleteMenu.Click += DeleteMenu_Click;
      menu.MenuItems.Add( deleteMenu );


   }

   private void DeleteMenu_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
      // put your code in here
   }
```

Comment: After you type += for deleteMenu.Click, visual studio might help you with creating the method.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)